# Viewing videos in pdf files

Tags: quicktime

I am trying to solve a problem with quicktime. I have a set of pdf files on CD that are instructional. Adobe reader is no longer working at all since the lastest "upgrade." I found I can open all of the files in Google chrome except the videos made with quicktime. Any ideas for me?

When I use Google chrome I simply drag the CD icon onto the browser window. Safari does not have a browser window, only a search bar. When I attempt to drag the file, nothing happens.

Comment: btw there is a community of people having this issue. Most of us are MAC users but PC users are having the issue as well due to adobe reader not working.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Chrome officially discontinued plug-in based content](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en) such as QuickTime videos. Try using another browser with a QuickTime plug-in.